# how to get dynamic value by ajax function call

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

on my web page i have text area like this
[image]

and i suppose to get data in textarea when i alternate the value of select box( or onChange event), so i used ajax function

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>                          
                function myCall() {
                    var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        type: "GET",            
                        dataType: "html"
                    });

                    request.done(function(msg) {
                        $("#mybox").html(msg);          
                    });

                    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                    });
                }

        </script>
```

and this is my select box code,

```
<select name="txtname" id="txtname" onChange="myCall()" >
    <option value="0">Select Age:</option>
    <option value="100083">100083</option>
    <option value="22-26">22-26</option>
    <option value="26-30">26-30</option>
    <option value="30-34">30-34</option>

    </select>
```

actualy i want to fetch record on the basis of select box value, this function working fine for static value but i am puzzled how to get data from data base..
and my ajax page coding is here..

```
<?php



$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("hmc", $con);


$sql="SELECT * FROM news WHERE name = '22-26'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>


                       <?php
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
        <tr>
<td>
<?php echo $row['news1'];?></h3></td>

</tr><br /><hr /><br />

<?php
}
?>




</div>
```

any idea will be appreciated...

Comment: i want to fetch record in textarea by onchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call is not proper, you need to pass your select box value to the php side, like this

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    type: "GET",            
                    dataType: "html",
                    data:"value="+$("#txtname").val();
                });
```

then use this value on php side using $_GET['value']

Comment: i paste all relevent data regarding ajax call...can you tell me how to get "value" on ajax.php page, i tried like this $q=$_GET['value'];

Comment: but on my original page its showing request failed: error...??